# Switch statment within Loop not working correctly

Tags: java

New to Java and I'm having troubles with my code, it's a switch statement within a while loop. I like to use letters or "char" instead of numbered cases "int" and I have 'q' to quit. Thanks for your input. This is the main code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class supraCritters {
    public static void main(String [] arguments) {
        Critter nastybat = new Critter();
        nastybat.health = 100;
        nastybat.mood = 50;
        nastybat.hunger = 25;

        System.out.println("Your critter has just been born,");
        System.out.println("here are the stats of your critter.");
        nastybat.checkStats();

        System.out.println("\nPlease choose a letter");
        System.out.println("[c]heck stats \n[f]eed \n[p]lay \n[r]ead \n[t]rain");
        System.out.println("[q]uit");

        Scanner sChoice = new Scanner(System.in);
        char choice = ' ';
        while (choice != 'q') {
            switch (choice) {
                case 'c':
                    nastybat.checkStats();
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    nastybat.feed();
                    break;
                case 'p':
                    nastybat.play();
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    nastybat.read();
                    break;
                case 't':
                    nastybat.train();
                    break;
                case 'q':
                System.out.println("good bye");
                    break;
                default:
                System.out.println("invalid entry");
                    break;
            }       
choice = sChoice.next().charAt(0);
        }   
    }
}
```

When I enter corresponding letter the loop doesn't show Input method or repeat and 'q' does nothing. Default displays "invalid entry" before input.

Code edited and still have problems.

Comment: You should move the code that gets the user input into the while loop

Comment: You've provided your code, and said that it's not working - but not said in what *way* it's not working, or given us any indication of the problem, basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished the code and it seems to work. Testing out the methods the object can use now.

Final

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class supraCritters {
    public static void main(String [] arguments) {
        Critter nastybat = new Critter();
        nastybat.health = 100;
        nastybat.mood = 50;
        nastybat.hunger = 25;

        System.out.println("Your critter has just been born,");
        System.out.println("here are the stats of your critter.");
        nastybat.checkStats();

        Scanner sChoice = new Scanner(System.in);
        char choice = ' ';
        while (choice != 'q') {
            switch (choice) {
                case 'c': case 'C':
                    nastybat.checkStats();
                    break;
                case 'f': case 'F':
                    nastybat.feed();
                    break;
                case 'p': case 'P':
                    nastybat.play();
                    break;
                case 'r': case 'R':
                    nastybat.read();
                    break;
                case 't': case 'T':
                    nastybat.train();
                    break;
            case 'q': case 'Q':
                System.out.println("good bye");
                    break;
                default:
                System.out.println("invalid entry");
                    break;
            }   
            System.out.println("\nPlease choose a letter");
            System.out.println("[c]heck stats \n[f]eed \n[p]lay \n[r]ead \n[t]rain");
            System.out.println("[q]uit");
            choice = sChoice.next().charAt(0);
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The input is taken only once, the first time! Therefore the loop always returns the same result. You should duplicate the getting input code inside the loop!

```
    Scanner sChoice = new Scanner(System.in);
    char choice = '';
    while (choice != 'q') {
        switch (choice) {
            case 'c':
                nastybat.checkStats();
                break;
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .

    choice = sChoice.next().charAt(0);
```

The first line gets input for the first switch run, and the one inside the loop gets the rest.

**UPDATE:**

The `choice = sChoice.next().charAt(0);` should be place at the final of the loop, if not, as **@proskor** says, when user hits '`q`' the program will return an '`invalid entry`'.

Comment: This would print "invalid entry" on 'q' before terminating.